# How do I let a subfolder be written to EXACTLY one time in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

To link together a group creator with group members, I would like the group creator to submit a connection string that group members can then use to join the group.

Once the connection string is created, however, I do not want anyone but the creator to remove or write over the string or data under the string.

In my javascript I can easily write a checking function to see if it exists:

```
function tryToAddConnectionString(uid, desiredConnectionString)
{
    firebase.database().ref('/connectionStrings/' + desiredConnectionString).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
         if(snapshot.val()==null)
         {
            //There is no data therefore there is no connection string, so create one.
            firebase.database().ref('connectionStrings/' + desiredConnectionString).set({
              owner: uid });
         }
         else
         {
           //Connection String already exists. Throw "already exists" message
         }
     });
}
```

But this does not stop a malicious hacker from going into his/her console and typing

```
firebase.database().ref('connectionStrings/' + desiredConnectionString).set(null);
```

Which will delete/take over the group.

Is there a rule I can set to fix this? Also, under

```
'/connectionStrings/'+desiredConnectionString+'members'
```

I want people to be able to add themselves as members.

To recap: I am looking for a rule which will allow anyone to create a connectionstring, but only the creator can delete the connection string or change the owner subfolder, but anyone can read/write the members folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do that with security rules:

```
//add a condition to verify that the node doesn't exist or the
//You must add to your node the aid of the creator
".write":"!data.exist() || auth.uid === data.child('creator')"
```

You can see what else you can configure here
[Security Rules Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-revisiting-advanced-example)

Comment: I you put your db structure it would be helpful

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I'm looking for